# finding where 2d list overlaps by value

Tags: python, numpy

One numpy 2d-array looks like this:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [1 5 0]]
```

Another numpy 2d array which looks like this:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2]
 [0 1 3 4 8 0 1 3 6 7 8 0 1 2 3 6 8]]
```

I want to get just the places where they "overlap":

```
[[0 2]
 [1 0]]
```

without using a for loop

Comment: shouldnt the first give `[0,1,2]`, or do I misunderstand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use intersect1d.
I called n1 the first array and n2 the second one.

The result is not exactly what you expected, but I believe it's correct.

```
intersection = np.intersect1d(n1, n2)
print(intersection)
[0 1 2]
```